Dinamis Query Loop template Custom Post Type dan Taxonomy di WordPress Blocks dengan PHP
Google Translated:

Hello everyone,
I’m trying to create custom blocks in WordPress that dynamically
display posts from custom post type that I’m creating, which is
“products”. I also want to sift the post based on certain taxonomy
that already exists.
How to use a loop query with PHP to retrieve this data? For example, I
want to display all the products by specific categories, and display
the title as well as the links of each product.
If there are examples of codes or explanations of the steps, I would
be very grateful!
Thank you very much!

Halo semua,
Saya sedang berusaha membuat blok kustom di WordPress yang secara dinamis menampilkan posting dari custom post type yang saya buat, yaitu "produk". Saya juga ingin menyaring posting berdasarkan taxonomy tertentu yang sudah ada.
Bagaimana cara menggunakan query loop dengan PHP untuk mengambil data ini? Misalnya, saya ingin menampilkan semua produk berdasarkan kategori tertentu, dan menampilkan judul serta tautan setiap produk.
Jika ada contoh kode atau penjelasan langkah-langkahnya, saya akan sangat berterima kasih!
Terima kasih banyak!
